# Camera preview via android application

Tags: android

In order to preview the camera, I've written code segments below. I could not get any preview. Can you help me to solve the problem?

I have configured my application with the permissions ;

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I have created the surface place

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

I've written code segments below to preview the camera ;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
}

 private void preview ( ) {

    try {
             camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
             camera.startPreview();
    } catch ( IOException void_) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture Image from camera using..

1. **Intent** (open default camera and capture image)
2. **Camera API** (get the image preview, also you can customize camera feature)

Please read this article step by step solution, I  found this is very helpful

[**Android Camera API - Tutorial**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

Let me know if you have any trouble in this, I have done already

**Edit:**

You can disable Camera using Admin Policy

check [**official document here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) with sample code
also [**this**](http://marakana.com/s/post/1291/android_device_policy_administration_tutorial) article may help you

Comment: how can I disable camera as admin ?

Comment: Is it possible to disable camera and any application can not open it ? ( with android device administration )

Answer (score 0):

Before the 4.0,The Android SDK provided by Google doesn't provide any camera emulation beyond a stand-in animation. Since Google haven't yet provided a working implementation (or even a date by which one will be available).

There is certain links which helps you to achieve your requirement.
Kindly refer [this](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source) and [this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/camera-preview-example-in-android-programming/) links.

Hope it may help you :)

Comment: That is not true. Starting with android 4.0, you can use your webcam as a camera preview in emulator.

Comment: @Shafi I appologies.Thanks to point me in right direction.I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

implement this class for camera preview and called its constructor in oncreate method of your activity.

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
        }
    }
}
```